# How can I get permissions of a document in sharepoint 2007 using web service?

Tags: permissions, web-services

I want to get permissions of a document in sharepoint 2007 using web service and export them to an excel file.
The result should be something like the following content:
document -> click "edit permission" -> sharepoint list all users have permission to current document.
My quest is how can I get this user list either by web service or sharepoint api ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

The out-of-the-box web services in SharePoint 2007 do not allow for permissions retrieval of anything other than a site or a list.

For individual permissions, you will need to create your own solution. That being said, you can find an example of a web service (for deployment to a SharePoint 2007 farm) that allows for retrieval of individual item permissions [here](http://www.codefornuts.com/2009/05/item-level-security-with-sharepoint-web.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is a Permissions Web Service (http://blahsite/_vti_bin/Permissions.asmx) that is provided for working with permissions. It provides methods for working with the permissions for a site or list only. It is very much surprising that it does not support managing permissions at item level with Web Services.

So, at this time, an OOTB web service to apply fine grained permissions does not exist. The best that can be done, is to the site or list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcpermissions.permissions.addpermission.aspx

You should be able to create a web service to do it though, here is an example:

http://www.codefornuts.com/2009/05/item-level-security-with-sharepoint-web.html